# Не могу запустить сервер - "cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Использую [этот туториал](https://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/create_a_rails_app). Вот что получается на 4-м шаге после ввода `rails server`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    4: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    3: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    2: from /home/denis/railsbridge/test_app/bin/spring:8:in `<top (required)>'
    1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
```

Версия Ruby стояла 2.6.3. Я предположил, что нужно установить более старую версию, поэтому, используя RVM, установил еще две `rvm install 2.5.0`  и `rvm install 2.2.2`. Переключение между ними и попытка снова выполнить `rails server` показывает то же самое. Еще я пробовал делать проброс 3000 порта в VirtualBox по какому-то совету из гугла, но еще вчера, и это не помогало.

**Обновляю пост прямо во время его написания** потому что именно сейчас появилась мысль удалить test_app и создать заново, используя Ruby 2.5.0. (до этого делал это не меняя версию Ruby)

Повторяю все шаги и на том же этапе вижу еще более непонятную для себя картину:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    19: from /usr/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
    18: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    17: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    16: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/cli.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
    15: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    14: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    13: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    12: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
    11: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
    10: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
     9: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
     8: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
     7: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
     6: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
     5: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
     4: from (eval):1:in `run_bundle'
     3: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/generators/app_base.rb:351:in `run_bundle'
     2: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/generators/app_base.rb:335:in `bundle_command'
     1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
```

Окей, возвращаю 2.6.3 `rvm use 2.6.3`, снова набираю `rails new test_app` с заменой файлов, затем `rails server` и вижу, что все прекрасно получилось, как и должно было изначально.

Кто-нибудь может рассказать, в чем была проблема и что привело к ее устранению? Потому что это, мягко говоря, не очевидно для меня, это мой второй день знакомства с терминалом, с Ruby и вообще с Linux.

Comment: Причин может быть много, но чаще всего проблема решается после переустановки бандлера - `gem install bundler`. Я причем не увидела этого этапа по вашей ссылке, может в этом и есть причина